# Taking filename input using a mac automator python script

Tags: python, macos

First off I want to say I am very new to python and the mac OS, normally program using C++ and using Windows.

What I am trying to do is create a drag and drop application that plots the data in the file using python/matplotlib. I have created a Run Shell Script (shell: /usr/bin/python) app using the Mac automator and the script runs as expected if I hard code the file path. However, I would like to change the script so it runs by dragging the file onto the app. This is my code thus far:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# This was code from an example online how to create a main like in C++
if __name == "__main__":
    main()
def main(input, *args, **kwargs):
    # If I hardcode the file name
    filename = '/usr/path/to/file/test.txt'
    # If I try to take the filename as an argument by dragging/dropping
    filename = sys.argv[1:]
    with open(filename) as f:
        # Code to read file and plot
```

The error the automator is giving me:

```
Run Shell Script failed - 1 error
    File "<string>", line 13
```

I am trying to avoid installing external software, managers request, hence why I am trying to use the already installed automator. Do I need to add some commands in the automator before the shell script on handling arguments, or am I missing something completely? This may be possible by using a bash script, but I do not know how to do that either